# What would be the best to retrieve all fields (or field instances) those utilizing filter formats?

Tags: 7, entities, input-formats

I want to get all fields that utilize input formats. What would be the good way to achieve it?

Comment: How are you defining "utilize input formats" exactly? Just short text/long text/with summary fields? Others?

Comment: @Clive By  "utilize input formats", I meant fields stores format name in their table column and output data per that input format.
Yeah, as per my knowledge short text/long text/with summary fields are among the list. However, I am wondering if any other fields are out there similarly using input format.